# JavaFX application main function not working

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I developed an application a few months ago and everything was working fine. Yesterday I was trying to compile my code again on a different computer and as soon as I openned up my project with netbeans (the IDE I developed my application) a pop-up window appeared saying that the default plataform has changed. Whn I try to run my application it said that are no available classes to run my application, although there really is (there's a static main function and everything is fine with it).

Besides this problem, I tried to run manually the file (right-click and run file) and the application started but it didn't work properly throwing a bunch of warnings that I have no ideia why

Today I tried to open the project on my work computer. IT also said that the java platform changed and if I try to run the same problem happens: it says there are no available classes to run the application. Now here is the weirdeist part: If I run manually the file containing the main function it works propperly.

Any Ideias?

Best Regards.

Comment: Check for version of java in both the computers. And also check for version of Java on which the application is been developed and check for referenced libraries in the build path/class path of the project.

Comment: Hey, In my personal computer the JDK is 1.8 and in my work computer is 1.7. But is that reason enough to explain why it doesn't find any main function?

Comment: There are chances that, when a application developed in higher version may not run in lower version. It happen for me when application developed in 1.7 did not run well with 1.6 because of features of 1.7 i have used in my application.

Comment: I install the JDK 8 in my work computer and that is indeed the fact that my application has problems running on my home computer. But I still have the problem that it doesn't find any main function on my code. Any ideias why?

Comment: JavaFX is integrated in JDK 8

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my problem. There was two problems: JDK version was different from the JDK I had when I developed my application and the other problem is that in order to have a main function, it needs to be inside a class that extends Application and also have an override to a Start function. For some reason I did not had this when I first developed altough it runned fine when I developed it.